# suddenly can't connect to mongo atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Solved.

yesterday i can connect to mongo atlas, but today suddenly i can't connect to mongo atlas.

The error message say:
*MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist:*

this is my mongo atlas network access:
[image]

Comment: Try adding the default IP "0.00..." That will allow all connections,

Comment: @SARANSURYA thanks, its already solved. The problem is my server network :D

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

i can't even use ping google.com, apt install blablabla

The problem is my server network.